# Sync dropbox with google drive or iCloud using gpg/python

Tags: python, encryption, gnupg

I have synced local folder on my system with Dropbox. When I drop a file in local folder it will be encrypted and synced to Dropbox using the 'watch' code. (Below is the respective code)

Now, I need to sync the same (local folder files with Dropbox which gets encrypted in Dropbox) with Google drive or iCloud drive, but I'm not sure where to begin.
Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

```
************************************************************
# Include the Dropbox and gnupg modules
import dropbox
import gnupg
import sys,os
from os import path

access_token = '**********************'
client = dropbox.client.DropboxClient(access_token)
print 'linked account: ', client.account_info()

gnupghome='C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU/GnuPG'
gpg = gnupg.GPG()

#encrypt file
temp = sys.argv[1]
file_path = path.abspath(temp)
outputfile = os.path.basename(file_path)
f = open(file_path, 'rb')
encryptionStatus = gpg.encrypt_file(f, recipients='pavancsms@gmail.com',output=outputfile)

print 'status: ', encryptionStatus.status
print 'stderr: ', encryptionStatus.stderr


f = open(outputfile, 'rb')
response = client.put_file(outputfile, f)
print "uploaded:", response

f = client.get_file(outputfile)
code = raw_input("Enter the passphrase here: ").strip()
p='C:/Proj/Decrypt/'+outputfile

decryptionStatus = gpg.decrypt_file(f,passphrase=code, output=p)
print 'status: ', decryptionStatus.status
print 'stderr: ', decryptionStatus.stderr
```

---

I need code to sync encrypted file from local folder in my system to Dropbox with Google drive or iCloud drive.

Answer (score 0):

For Google Drive, you can use PyDrive. It is a module that simplifies the Google Python API library for Google Drive. You will need to get an OAuth Token and then use the API to sync the encrypted folder.
PyDrive: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyDrive

iCloud Drive on the other hand is a completely different story. Apple is very restrictive of their APIs and there isn't a single iCloud Drive module for Python. This module https://github.com/picklepete/pyicloud has support for iCloud but not for iCloud Drive. You'll need to roll your own module.